# "disabled" property not working for date/time edit boxes displaying a date/time picker

Tags: xpages, wai-aria

An editbox with its display type set to "Date/Time" and with the "Display date/time picker pop up" option checked obviously ignores an checked "Disabled" property (is this a bug?); without the picker pop up option the control can be disabled as any other editbox.

If however I check the control's "readonly" property along with its "Show disbled control for read only" property then the control appears to be rendered as "disabled"; the html source for the INPUT however shows these attributes

```
readonly="" aria-readonly="true"
```

Question: are there any possible side effects using that workaround? So far I don't have any experience with aria attributes and the like.

Comment: This question seems to similar to the one described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251604/how-can-i-allow-selection-of-a-date-using-the-calandar-button-but-disable-typing/11255742.

Comment: @Naveen: same type of control, but different goal, as I was seeking for a way to *completely* disable the date picker field but still show that it's not just static text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed an existing issue, the disabled property doesn't work on the Date Time Picker. This should be fixed in 854 (usual provisos apply).

Comment: thanks Paul, that at least confirms that this can't be wanted behaviour ;)

Answer (score 0):

Setting all three attributes  disabled, readonly, & showReadonlyAsDisabled,  then the DateTime field shows up but is not functional.

```
[xp:inputText id="inputText2" **disabled="true"** **readonly="true"**
    **showReadonlyAsDisabled="true"**]
    [xp:dateTimeHelper id="dateTimeHelper1"][/xp:dateTimeHelper]
    [xp:this.converter]
        [xp:convertDateTime type="date"][/xp:convertDateTime]
    [/xp:this.converter]
[/xp:inputText]
```